# How do I download all existing email on an Exchange Server to Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I am running out of space on my hosted exchange server. I usually use Outlook Web Access to access my email. I have configured Outlook to read my email, but it leaves all the email on the server. How can I instruct it to pull all email down and **remove** it from the server?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to pull down your email would be to export the mailbox contents to a PST.  This will download all of your email to a single blob that you can move to another computer, or even upload to another Exchange mailbox.

Here's a quick how to.

http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/default.asp?id=783

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this now. Will this also remove files from the server? It will take forever to manually delete them.

Comment: No, performing an export will not delete the files from the server.  Do you just want to remove the messages, but keep the mailbox afterwards, or delete the entire mailbox?

Comment: I want the mailbox to remain the same, I just want to move where the emails are being stored from the server to my machine.

Comment: Without admin access to the exchange environment, the best way to delete all of the messages using Outlook will probably be to shift select all of the messages and then hold down shift + delete  to delete the emails permanently.  Make sure of course that the export to a PST has completed before your perform the shift delete.

Comment: The .pst file this creates for me contains the emails when they already exist on my machine, but all emails archived on the Exchange server are still just "links" (not sure what the right term is), so that the .pst file isn't "self-contained"

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Outlook for a while but if memory serves there are two ways to go about this:

- Create a local pst file.
- Connect to the server as a normal
  exchange client.
- Highlight all the emails you want
  to keep
- Cut and past them to your pst
  file.

**OR**

- Create a local pst file.
- Connect to your server as a pop3
  client

By default, Outlook deletes messages from the server after it retreives them when configured as a pop3 client.

Coincidentally, I've done the exact opposite of what you're try to do. I had been downloading all my email to a pst file when I found out my computer was going to be replaced. I wound up moving all my emails to the server for safe keeping.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to reduce the space used on Hosted exchange you can also just create an archive in outlook, set a date to archive up until, this will create a new PST file that is stored on your local computer and it will remove the messages from the live exchange account. At least this way you have the mail should you ever need to refer back to it.

Answer (score 1):

Click on FILE, then click on account settings, then account settings under that.  You will then double click on your account name to bring up Internet E-mail Settings.  Click the Advanced tab.  The next pop up window has a check box on the bottom that says Leave a copy of messages on the server.  Un-check that box and the messages will be downloaded to Outlook and not left on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Its not always sensible to delete old emails for various reasons, but it is an easy way to save space. Espicially ones that have large attatchments, download the attachments then you can delete the email.

Comment: This isn't helpful and does not at all answer any part of my question.

Comment: It was a serious answer. How is this not helpful?

Comment: It does not answer any part of my question. "How can I instruct [outlook] to pull all email down and remove it from the server?"

Comment: This is a great example of explaining why an answer should be down voted! Seriously, for all the times that down votes to not get explained to the poster. No offense, just trying to explain good process here.