# Where is my email located?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am using outlook 2000 with a login id to a exchange server of our company.

I would like to ask, where is my email located? Is it in the exchange server or in my computer?

If the email is in the exchange, can I make a local folder in outlook and put them there? Ultimately I want to manipulate the content of some emails, so I need to know how to access the email via VBA or other open source tool/plugin/extension.

P.S. I've watch this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/89380/how-do-i-download-all-existing-email-on-an-exchange-server-to-outlook), does the pst file mean the personal folder in outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that the data is located on the exchange server, and that you should write an Outlook Plug-In with [VSTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office). This way, the physical location of the data is not important, as long as Outlook has access to it.